# Accessing multi dimensional list in managed c++

Tags: .net, generics, c++-cli

in C# I have something like that (my real problem has more dimensions):

```
        List<List<int>> testlist = new List<List<int>>();
        int yadda = testlist[0][0];
```

What is the equivalent in C++?

I tried:

```
List<List<int>^>^ testlist = gcnew List<List<int>^>();
int yadda = testlist[0][0];
```

but this gives error "System::Collections::Generic::List::default[int]::get [with T=System::Collections::Generic::List ^]" cannot be called with the given argument list argument types are: (int, int) object type is: System::Collections::Generic::List ^> ^.

The only way I get it working is

```
    List<List<int>^>^ testlist = gcnew List<List<int>^>();
int yadda = ((List<int>^)testlist[0])[0];
```

But this is not very readable with cast operators for every dimension.

So is there a better way to get an element of a multi dimensional list in C++?

Comment: list in list in list.. is bad practice for the obvious reason. Can't you change this nd make a nice oo model out of it

Comment: Not use lists at all? Write down your design and use-cases, and see if lists are really needed. Especially since you use random-access on the list, which will always be O(n) (so if you have a very long lists, containing very long lists, it will be O(n*n), in other words very slow). In standard C++ a better solution would be [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: I use a list, because elements are added by user on the fly and I have no performance problems, as they are not very long.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of lists you can do this simply like this:

```
list< list<int> > testlist = list< list<int> >(0,list<int>(0,0));
```

Note the white space after the the innermost `list<int>`. It's necessary to write `list<list<int> >` instead of `list<list<int>>` because in the second case the compiler will interpret it as operator `>>` and therefore give an error.

If you want to access elements like `[i][j]` use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I need a standard .NET type, because this list is created in C# and the access to the list is made in C++.